# Potential dynamic memory problems

Tags: c++, memory-management, arduino, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am creating an Arduino device using C++. I need a stack object with variable size and variable data types. Essentially this stack needs to be able to be resized and used with bytes, chars, ints, doubles, floats, shorts, and longs.

I have a basic class setup, but with the amount of dynamic memory allocation that is required, I wanted to make sure that my use of data frees enough space for the program to continue without memory problems. This does not use std methods, but instead built in versions of those for the Arduino.

For clarification, my question is: **Are there any potential memory problems in my code?**

NOTE: This is not on the Arduino stack exchange because it requires an in depth knoweledge of C/C++ memory allocation that could be useful to all C and C++ programmers.

Here's the code:

**Stack.h**

```
#pragma once

class Stack {
public:
  void init();
  void deinit();

  void push(byte* data, size_t data_size);
  byte* pop(size_t data_size);

  size_t length();

private:
  byte* data_array;
};
```

**Stack.cpp**

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Stack.h"

void Stack::init() {
  // Initialize the Stack as having no size or items
  data_array = (byte*)malloc(0);
}

void Stack::deinit() {
  // free the data so it can be re-used
  free(data_array);
}

// Push an item of variable size onto the Stack (byte, short, double, int, float, long, or char)
void Stack::push(byte* data, size_t data_size) {
  data_array = (byte*)realloc(data_array, sizeof(data_array) + data_size);
  for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(data); i++)
    data_array[sizeof(data_array) - sizeof(data) + i] = data[i];
}

// Pop an item of variable size off the Stack (byte, short, double, int, float, long, or char)
byte* Stack::pop(size_t data_size) {
  byte* data;

  if(sizeof(data_array) - data_size >= 0) {
    data = (byte*)(&data_array + sizeof(data_array) - data_size);
    data_array = (byte*)realloc(data_array, sizeof(data_array) - data_size);
  } else {
    data = NULL;
  }

  // Make sure to free(data) when done with the data from pop()!
  return data;
}

// Return the sizeof the Stack
size_t Stack::length() {
  return sizeof(data_array);
}
```

Comment: In general, yes there are massive problems. You should rather rely on the [Dynamic memory management](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) features of c++.

Comment: For a starter using dynamic memory allocation and full-grown OOP on such a small architecture like AVR is a bad idea in general. So yes, there are problems with your code. Let that apart: This is not a review site. If there is a probem, state it. See [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some minor code bugs, apparently, which -- although important -- are easily resolved. The following answer only applies to the overall design of this class:

There is nothing wrong with just the code that is shown.

But only the code that's shown. No opinion is rendered on any code that's not shown.

And, it's fairly likely that there are going to be massive problems, and memory leaks, in the rest of the code which will attempt to use this class.

It's going to very, very easy to use this class in a way that leaks or corrupts memory. It's going to be much harder to use this class correctly, and much easier to screw up. The fact that these functions themselves appear to do their job correctly is not going to help if all you have to do is sneeze in the wrong direction, and end up with these functions not being used in the proper order, or sequence.

Just to name the first two readily apparent problems:

1) Failure to call `deinit()`, when any instance of this class goes out of scope and gets destroyed, will leak memory. Every time you use this class, you have to be cognizant of when the instance of this class goes out of scope and gets destroyed. It's easy to keep track of every time you create an instance of this class, and it's easy to remember to call `init()` every time. But keeping track of every possible way an instance of this class could go out of scope and get destroyed, so that you must call `deinit()` and free up the internal memory, is much harder. It's very easy to not even realize when that happens.

2) If an instance of this class gets copy-constructed, or the default assignment operator gets invoked, this is guaranteed to result in memory corruption, with an extra side-helping of a memory leak.

Note that you don't have to go out of your way to write code that copy-constructs, or assigns one instance of the object to another one. The compiler will be more than happy to do it for you, if you do not pay attention.

Generally, the best way to avoid these kinds of problems is to make it impossible to happen, by using the language correctly. Namely:

1) Following the [RAII design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization). Get rid of `init()` and `deinit()`. Instead, do this work in the object's constructor and destructor.

2) Either deleting the copy constructor and the assignment operator, or implementing them correctly. So, if instances of this class should never be copy-constructed or assigned-to, it's much better to have the compiler yell at you, if you accidentally write some code that does that, instead of spending a week tracking down where that happens. Or, if the class can be copy-constructed or assigned, doing it properly.

Of course, if there would only be a small number of instances of this class, it should be possible to safely use it, with tight controls, and lots of care, without doing this kind of a redesign. But, even if it were the case, it's always better to do the job right, instead of shrugging this off now, but then later deciding to expand the use of this class in more places, and then forgetting about the fact that this class is so error-prone.

P.S.: a few of the minor bugs that I mentioned in the beginning:

```
data_array = (byte*)realloc(data_array, sizeof(data_array) + data_size);
```

This can't be right. `data_array` is a `byte *`, so `sizeof(data_array)` will always be a compile-time constant, which would be `sizeof(byte *)`. That's obviously not what you want here. You need to explicitly keep track of the allocated array's size.

The same general bug appears in several other places here, but it's easily fixed. The overall class design is the bigger problem.